# Flutter: crash when creating multiple Widgets at the same time

Tags: flutter

I developed a book reader project, where it is necessary to create several Widgets at the same time so that after they are created I can calculate the size of all of them together. But when creating these widgets, it causes a slight app crash, depending on the user's device, it lasts around 2 to 4 seconds. This freeze is general where no action can be taken, I even tried putting a CircularProgressIndicator on top of the screen and even the animation is frozen.

Is there any possibility to create these widgets asynchronously? For example, when starting the screen and loading them, being able to leave a "loading" until finished and then display them. Preventing the app from freezing.

Or if there is any creation alternative for these widgets?

The structure consists of this: they are Html widgets (flutter_html package) that are placed inside a Wrap that distributes them to create a horizontal scroll.

Thanks!

In my project, several widgets are created at the same time, which is causing the app to freeze. I need to set a loading or improve performance.